# UITextView interferes scrolling of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitextview

The problem I am encountering now is that there is a `UITextView` component in `UIScrollView` and that `UITextView` component will interfere the scrolling of `UIScrollView`, i.e. when a user's finger is on that `UITextView` to scroll the whole `UIScrollView`, the screen won't scroll. The content in the `UITextView` is dynamic, i.e. the size of `UITextView` component is dynamic. The worst case is the whole screen is occupied by the `UITextView` and users won't be able to scroll the screen at all.

The `UITextView` is disabled for editing. I choose `UITextView` instead of `UILabel` because I want to detect phone number & link in the supplied text and utilize the built-in function to invoke dialer and browser when users click the phone number or link.

Any suggestion about how I can solve this problem or any clue about why this happens are all appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: please include some code so we may debug or rather see whats going on, and maybe a pic of the simulator please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITextView inherits from UIScroll view so it has a property scrollEnabled. Just put it to false!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a storyboard or nib file, select your `UITextView` and uncheck Scrolling Enabled in Interface Builder.

[image: Uncheck Scrolling Enabled]

Otherwise, do this:

```
textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the screen capture. :) Sorry that I can only accept one answer and I gave it to Matlecu because s/he answered the first.

Comment: @toppest No problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the property `scrollEnabled`, you also have the property `userInterationEnabled` that disable(if you set it to `FALSE`/`NO`) any touch events on the view (scrolling included, of course). Hope it helps, specially for other situations cos in your case it makes the same effect as disabling the scroll.

Comment: Thanks. Disable scrollEnabled is good enough for my purpose. For my purpose, I can't set userInteractionEnabled to false since I want to utilize TextView's built-in feature to dial a number or open a link.